# Java Merge 2 Custom Class results

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 custom Java classes;

```
private MyCustomClass1 obj1;
private MyCustomClass2 obj2;
```

Each of them has multiple attributes as below;

```
MyCustomClass1 {
attr1,
attr2,
commonattrId,
attr3
}


MyCustomClass2 {
attr4,
attr5,
commonattrId,
attr6
}
```

So as you can see, there is a common attribute in each of them (commonattrId) which just to add is a Long

There is also a composite class defined as below;

```
MyCompositeClass {
    MyCustomClass1 obj1;
    MyCustomClass2 obj2;
}
```

Now one of my query execution returns below list;

> List myList1

and there is another query execution which returns me below list;

> List myList2

My question is can I combine the above 2 lists given I have a commonattrId ?

Comment: Are java-8-style lambdas an option for you?

Comment: Just to clarify: "Combine them" means creating a new list that contains `MyCompositeClass` objects where `obj1.commonattrId == obj2.commonattrId`???

Answer (score 0):

slightly long but the idea is to override equals in `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<MyClass1> myClass1s = new ArrayList<MyClass1>();

    myClass1s.add(new MyClass1(1, 1));
    myClass1s.add(new MyClass1(2, 2));

    List<MyClass2> myClass2s = new ArrayList<MyClass2>();

    myClass2s.add(new MyClass2(3, 1));
    myClass2s.add(new MyClass2(4, 2));

    List<MyComposite> allMyClasses = new ArrayList<MyComposite>();
    for(MyClass1 m : myClass1s) { // note: you should take the shorte of the two lists
        int index = myClass2s.indexOf(m);
        if(index != -1) {
            allMyClasses.add(new MyComposite(m, myClass2s.get(index)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(allMyClasses);
}

static class MyClass1 {
    int attr1;
    long commonAttrId;

    public MyClass1(int attr, long commonAttr) {
        this.attr1 = attr;
        this.commonAttrId = commonAttr;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 83 * hash + (int) (this.commonAttrId ^ (this.commonAttrId >>> 32));
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if(obj instanceof MyClass2) {
            return this.commonAttrId == ((MyClass2)obj).commonAttrId;
        }
        if(obj instanceof MyClass1) {
            return this.commonAttrId == ((MyClass1)obj).commonAttrId;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "attr1=" + attr1 + ", commonAttrId=" + commonAttrId;
    }
}

static class MyClass2 {
    int attr2;
    long commonAttrId;

    public MyClass2(int attr, long commonAttr) {
        this.attr2 = attr;
        this.commonAttrId = commonAttr;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 83 * hash + (int) (this.commonAttrId ^ (this.commonAttrId >>> 32));
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if(obj instanceof MyClass1) {
            return this.commonAttrId == ((MyClass1)obj).commonAttrId;
        }
        if(obj instanceof MyClass2) {
            return this.commonAttrId == ((MyClass2)obj).commonAttrId;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "attr2=" + attr2 + ", commonAttrId=" + commonAttrId;
    }
}

static class MyComposite {
    MyClass1 myClass1;
    MyClass2 myClass2;

    public MyComposite(MyClass1 a, MyClass2 b) {
        myClass1 = a;
        myClass2 = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "myClass1=" + myClass1 + ", myClass2=" + myClass2;
    }
}
```

I don't know all the parameters of your problem but there are probably better ways to do this. For example: have both `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` inherit from a common class (i.e. `MyBaseClass`) and create a collection of that instead of the composite class `MyCompositeClass`.
Or instead of `List`s you could have sets and create a set intersection.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map from id to the object for one of the lists and then iterate through the other to create the new List using the data from the map.

```
List<MyCompositeClass> combine(List<MyCustomClass1> myList1, List<MyCustomClass2> myList2) {
   // create map
   Map<Long, MyCustomClass1> idToObj = new HashMap<>();
   for (MyCustomClass1 o : myList1) {
       idToObj.put(o.commonattrId, o);
   }
   // construct result list
   List<MyCompositeClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
   for (MyCustomClass2 o : myList2) {
       MyCustomClass1 o1 = map.get(o.commonattrId);
       if (o1 != null) {
           MyCompositeClass combined = new MyCompositeClass();
           combined.obj1 = o1;
           combined.obj2 = o;
           result.add(combined);
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

This will only add all possible combinations of objects from both lists, if `commonattrId` values are pairwise distinct in each list, but since the field name has "Id" as suffix, I made an educated guess...